# How to use sed and regex to find and replace a string present inside a file?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a file that contains lines of the type -

```
find /home/subd1/subd2/$dirname -type d 
find /home1/subd1/subd2/$dirname -type d 
find /home10/subd1/subd2/$dirname -type d
```

I want to find `/home/` or `/home<no>/` and replace it with DIFFERENT `/home/` or `/home<no>/`. Basically, find and replace -

```
/home with /home2 or
/home2 with /home3 or
/home3 with /home
etc.
```

I tried doing -

```
sed -i 's/\/home.?\//\/home3\//g' /path/to/file
sed -i 's/\/home[\d]?\//\/home3\//g' /path/to/file
```

But this made no change to the file.
Am i missing something here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\d` is not supported by `sed`. Try using `[0-9]` instead.

As an example I tried the sample file you provided

```
find /home/subd1/subd2/$dirname -type d 
find /home1/subd1/subd2/$dirname -type d 
find /home10/subd1/subd2/$dirname -type d
```

When given `sed -i 's;/home[0-9]*/;/home3/;g' test.txt` (Using `;` as the sed delimiter so that I don't have to escape every `/`) the file was edited to

```
find /home3/subd1/subd2/$dirname -type d 
find /home3/subd1/subd2/$dirname -type d 
find /home3/subd1/subd2/$dirname -type d
```

It's important to note that this will change *every* instance of `/home/` and `/home<no>/` to be the same new values (in this case `/home3/`). I think that this is your objective, but if it's not you will need a different `sed` expression